# How do I use matplotlib autopct?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, plot-annotations

I'd like to create a matplotlib pie chart which has the value of each wedge written on top of the wedge.

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) suggests I should use `autopct` to do this.

> autopct: [ None | format string |
>   format function ]
>       If not None, is a string or function used to label the wedges with
>   their numeric value. The label will be
>   placed inside the wedge. If it is a
>   format string, the label will be
>   fmt%pct. If it is a function, it will
>   be called.

Unfortunately, I'm unsure what this format string or format function is supposed to be.

Using this basic example below, how can I display each numerical value on top of its wedge?

```
plt.figure()
values = [3, 12, 5, 8] 
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
plt.pie(values, labels=labels) #autopct??
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

`autopct` enables you to display the percent value using Python string formatting. For example, if `autopct='%.2f'`, then for each pie wedge, the format string is `'%.2f'` and the numerical percent value for that wedge is `pct`, so the wedge label is set to the string `'%.2f'%pct`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
values = [3, 12, 5, 8] 
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct='%.2f')
plt.show()
```

yields
[image: Simple pie chart with percentages]

You can do fancier things by supplying a callable to `autopct`. To display both the percent value and the original value, you could do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make the pie circular by setting the aspect ratio to 1
plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
values = [3, 12, 5, 8] 
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 

def make_autopct(values):
    def my_autopct(pct):
        total = sum(values)
        val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
        return '{p:.2f}%  ({v:d})'.format(p=pct,v=val)
    return my_autopct

plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=make_autopct(values))
plt.show()
```

[image: Pie chart with both percentages and absolute numbers.]

Again, for each pie wedge, matplotlib supplies the percent value `pct` as the argument, though this time it is sent as the argument to the function `my_autopct`. The wedge label is set to `my_autopct(pct)`.

Answer (score 17):

You can do:

```
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=lambda p : '{:.2f}%  ({:,.0f})'.format(p,p * sum(values)/100))
```

Answer (score 14):

Using lambda and format may be better

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

path = r"C:\Users\byqpz\Desktop\DATA\raw\tips.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path, engine='python', encoding='utf_8_sig')

days = df.groupby('day').size()

sns.set()
days.plot(kind='pie', title='Number of parties on different days', figsize=[8,8],
          autopct=lambda p: '{:.2f}%({:.0f})'.format(p,(p/100)*days.sum()))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

`autopct` enables you to display the percentage value of each slice using Python string formatting.

For example,

```
autopct = '%.1f' # display the percentage value to 1 decimal place
autopct = '%.2f' # display the percentage value to 2 decimal places
```

If you want to show the % symbol on the pie chart, you have to write/add:

```
autopct = '%.1f%%'
autopct = '%.2f%%'
```

Answer (score 8):

As `autopct` is a [function used to label the wedges with their numeric value](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html), you can write there any label or format items quantity with it as you need. The easiest approach for me to show percentage label is using lambda:

```
autopct = lambda p:f'{p:.2f}%'
```

or for some cases you can label data as

```
autopct = lambda p:'any text you want'
```

and for your code, to show percentage you can use:

```
plt.figure()
values = [3, 12, 5, 8] 
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=lambda p:f'{p:.2f}%, {p*sum(values)/100 :.0f} items')
plt.show()
```

and result will be like:

[image: result]

Answer (score 7):

```
val=int(pct*total/100.0)
```

should be

```
val=int((pct*total/100.0)+0.5)
```

to prevent rounding errors.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of matplotlib gallary and hints from StackOverflow users, I came up with the following pie chart.
the autopct shows amounts and kinds of ingredients.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

reciepe= ["480g Flour", "50g Eggs", "90g Sugar"]
amt=[int(x.split('g ')[0]) for x in reciepe]
ing=[x.split()[-1] for x in reciepe]
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5), subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'))
wadges, text, autotext=ax.pie(amt, labels=ing, startangle=90,
                              autopct=lambda p:"{:.0f}g\n({:.1f})%".format(p*sum(amt)/100, p),
                              textprops=dict(color='k', weight='bold', fontsize=8))
ax.legend(wadges, ing,title='Ingredents', loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(0.35,0.85,0,0))
```

[Piechart showing the amount and of percent of a sample recipe ingredients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkJho.jpg)

[Pie chart showing the salary and percent of programming Language users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE9pD.jpg)