# How to replace auto-labelled relative values by absolute values in a pie plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm creating a pie-chart according to the matplotlib-demo: https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html

The percentage of each `frac` seems to be auto-labelled. How can I replace these auto-labelled relative values (%) plotted on the pie-chart by absolute values from `fracs[]`?

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19338) upstream.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`help(pie)` says:

```
  *autopct*: [ *None* | format string | format function ]
    If not *None*, is a string or function used to label the
    wedges with their numeric value.  The label will be placed inside
    the wedge.  If it is a format string, the label will be ``fmt%pct``.
    If it is a function, it will be called.
```

so you can turn the percentages back into original values by multiplying by the total size of the pie and dividing by 100:

```
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
total = sum(fracs)
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
    autopct=lambda(p): '{:.0f}'.format(p * total / 100),
    shadow=True, startangle=90)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: To show both percentage and total: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170246/how-do-i-use-matplotlib-autopct

Comment: That should be `lambda p` in that code, without the parentheses.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye: The parentheses were legal in Python 2.7 — note the date the answer was written.