# Create a bar plot and pie plot with 3 columns

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

My DataFrame is below

```
  Month  Sales2015  Sales2016
0    Q3       0.00   13208.52
1    Q4   10500.78   23114.91
2    Q2       0.00    6627.00
3    Q1   19881.00   13254.00
4    Q3    3684.48       0.00
```

My code is below

```
sa[['Month','Sales2015','Sales2016']].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: sa[['Month','Sales2015','Sales2016']].plot(kind='bar')]

But this graph is not correct. I need to

- Compare quarter-wise sales in 2015 and 2016 in a bar plot
- Create a pie chart with Month and Sales2016

Comment: do you want add Sales by Month and year, then create the graph for each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html).

```
df.groupby('Month').sum().plot(kind='bar')
#print(df.groupby('Month').first())

#       Sales2015  Sales2016
#Month                      
#Q1      19881.00   13254.00
#Q2          0.00    6627.00
#Q3          0.00   13208.52
#Q4      10500.78   23114.91
```

[image]

---

```
df.groupby('Month').sum().plot.pie(subplots=(1,len(df.columns[1:])),figsize=(10,10))

#array([<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f1303f64a20>,
#       <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f1303f29048>],
#      dtype=object)
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain this `for i,ax in enumerate(axs):
    agg_df.plot.pie(y=list_sales[i],ax=ax)
`

Comment: with plt.subplots two axes are generated where to draw the graph and with the loop reference is made to it. But you can use the second solution that I just published

Comment: How to get the values also on the char like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088236/how-to-have-actual-values-in-matplotlib-pie-chart-displayed-python`