# Pandas pie plot actual values for multiple graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to print actual values in pies instead of percentage, for one dimensonal series this helps:

[Matplotlib pie-chart: How to replace auto-labelled relative values by absolute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171021/matplotlib-pie-chart-how-to-replace-auto-labelled-relative-values-by-absolute-v)

But when I try to create multiple pies it won't work.

```
d = {'Yes':pd.Series([825, 56], index=["Total", "Last 2 Month"]), 'No':pd.Series([725, 73], index=["Total", "Last 2 Month"])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.T
def absolute_value(val):
    a  = np.round(val/100.*df.values, 0)
    return a

df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 6),autopct=absolute_value)
plt.show()
```

How can I make this right?

Thanks.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19338) upstream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hacky solution would be to index the dataframe within the `absolute_value` function, considering that this function is called exactly once per value in that dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Yes':pd.Series([825, 56], index=["Total", "Last 2 Month"]), 
     'No':pd.Series([725, 73], index=["Total", "Last 2 Month"])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.T

i = [0]
def absolute_value(val):
    a  = df.iloc[i[0]%len(df),i[0]//len(df)]
    i[0] += 1
    return a

df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 6),autopct=absolute_value)
plt.show()
```

The other option is to plot the pie charts individually by looping over the columns.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Yes':pd.Series([825, 56], index=["Total", "Last 2 Month"]), 
     'No':pd.Series([725, 73], index=["Total", "Last 2 Month"])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.T
print df.iloc[:,0].sum()

def absolute_value(val, summ):
    a  = np.round(val/100.*summ,0)
    return a

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.columns))
for i,ax in enumerate(axes):
    df.iloc[:,i].plot.pie(ax=ax,autopct=lambda x: absolute_value(x,df.iloc[:,i].sum()))
plt.show()
```

In both cases the output would look similar to this

[image]