# How to position donut subplots one inside the other using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, donut-chart

I am trying to position my three donut subplots one inside the other for comparison but unable to find a simple way of doing it. I am not sure how I cannot define three separate radii for the three subplots.
Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
df_plot.transpose().plot.pie(title="Status vs opinions on changes in monastery",
 subplots=True, startangle=0, legend=None,radius= 1,
autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=1.2,
wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3, edgecolor='white')
)

plt.show()
```

[image: Link to my donut chart]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add percent labels to three-level donut chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481983/add-percent-labels-to-three-level-donut-chart)

Comment: @accdias Hi this does not help since in the link you suggested all the three plots are separately defined. I want to know a way to this with the panda dataframes subplot. (I am not sure how I cannot define three separate radius for the three subplots)

Comment: You necessarily need to split your data into three parts and plot a one by one. In that sense, please do not claim that it doesn't help. Instead you may ask for further clarification if you don't know how to proceed. This is best done by sharing a [mcve] of your attempt inside the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sure I will try to divide the data into three parts and try it however I initially want to know if there are any easier ways to concatenate the three graphs by hard-coding their radii in some way. Thanks.