# How to make matplotlib autopct a function of the label name?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a simple pie chart in Python:

```
values = [3, 5, 12, 8]
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
plt.pie(values, labels)
```

Which looks something like:

[image: pie chart]

I also have a dictionary of values:

```
dictionary = {'a': 0.31, 'b': 0.11, 'c' : 0.07, 'd': 0.12}
```

I would like to label each slice with its corresponding value in the dictionary. How do I do that? I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170246/how-do-i-use-matplotlib-autopct) which demonstrated how to pass extra arguments to the `autopct` function, but it seems that the arguments must be the same for each slice, whereas in this case, they are different for each slice.

Comment: What is the relevance of `values` to the values in the `dictionary`? Are they just  integer values to keep the approximate ratios of the floating point values of `dictionary`?

Comment: They are not related. The values in `dictionary` are a function of the label name.

Comment: You said they are not related then accepted a solution that uses the values in the dictionary to draw the pi chart!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that what you are looking for is to label each piece with the share of the pie defined as values in the dict, is that right ?

Something like:

```
dictionary = {'a': 0.31, 'b': 0.11, 'c' : 0.07, 'd': 0.12}
labels = dictionary.keys()
sizes = dictionary.values()
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.show()
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I was hoping to have the labels on the slices instead of next to them, but I guess that will do.