# cannot add % sign to show on the pie

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pie-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ4Fb.png)Im plotting Pie with values shown as % but values appear without "%" sign, I,m trying to add it("%") as string but says format is incomplete, when i remove it, it prints values without sign

I m using:

```
df['Sold Contract'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), legend= True, autopct ="%.1f")
```

And trying to USE :

```
df['Sold Contract'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), legend= True, autopct ="%.1f%")

or 
autopct ="{%.1f}%"
or
autopct ="(%.1f) %"
or 
autopct =("%.1f %")
```

Expecting to see % sign next to values on the PIE

Comment: Look at this answer - it shows exactly what you are trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170354/6317990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that is a very good question.
The main reason is that normally when you want to use a special character inside a string as a character(", ', ) you use the backslash(/) before that character(", ', \).
In the case of the % sign, you use two signs(so %%) inside your string to print one percent sign
So: print("This is a percent sign: %%") -> This is a percent sign: %
I hope that helps!

Comment: Wow it worked! thanks: 

df['Sold Contract'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), legend= True, autopct ="%.1f%%")